# Elixir - Dynamically setting request headers for stripity_stripe library

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, http-proxy

I am using stripity_stripe library and want to send some requests to stripe through a proxy server but not the others. So, I am trying to dynamically send hackney options on some requests. I looked into the code and documentation of stripity_stripe library but couldn’t find any example to send the hackney options related to proxy. I figured out to set the proxy related information in the config.ex file and it is working fine, but since it is set in the configuration, it will be applied to all the requests.

```
config :stripity_stripe,
  api_key: System.get_env("STRIPE_API_KEY"),
  hackney_opts: [
    {:ssl_options, [cacertfile: "CERT.pem"]},
    {:proxy, System.get_env("PROXY_SANDBOX_BASE_URL")},
    {:proxy_auth,
     {System.get_env("PROXY_SANDBOX_USERNAME"), System.get_env("PROXY_SANDBOX_PASSWORD")}}
  ]
```

I found a function request() in stripity_stripe to dynamically send headers and options but could not succeed to send these options successfully. Here is how I tried it:

```
Stripe.API.request(params, :post, "tokens", %{},
      hackney_opts: [
        {:ssl_options, [cacertfile: "/Users/apple/.ssh/CERT.pem"]},
        {:proxy, System.get_env("PROXY_SANDBOX_BASE_URL")},
        {:proxy_auth,
         {System.get_env("PROXY_SANDBOX_USERNAME"), System.get_env("PROXY_SANDBOX_PASSWORD")}}
      ]
    )
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I get lost in the hackney docs, so hopefully someone wiser than me can weigh in, but looking briefly at the code, try omitting the `hackney_options` key when you call `Stripe.API.request/5`, and just put the list of opts e.g. `Stripe.API.request(params, :post, "tokens", %{}, ssl_options: [cacertfile: "/Users/apple/.ssh/CERT.pem"], proxy: System.get_env("VGS_SANDBOX_BASE_URL"))`

Or... you can override the client module by setting the `:hackney` option in your config, e.g. to replace it with `HTTPoison` or some other client (which might seem silly given that HTTPoison uses `:hackney` itself).

Comment: @Everett that was it, directly passing the options worked! Thank you very much

Comment: cool, I added it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omit the `hackney_options` key when you call `Stripe.API.request/5` -- just pass the list of opts directly, e.g.

```
Stripe.API.request(
  params, 
  :post, 
  "tokens", 
  %{}, 
  ssl_options: [cacertfile: "/Users/apple/.ssh/CERT.pem"],  
  proxy: System.get_env("VGS_SANDBOX_BASE_URL")
)
```

Remember that when the last argument is a keyword list, the brackets are often omitted.  You could include them to help make it easier to see which things belong to that final argument e.g.

```
Stripe.API.request(
  params, 
  :post, 
  "tokens", 
  %{}, 
  [
    ssl_options: [cacertfile: "/Users/apple/.ssh/CERT.pem"],  
    proxy: System.get_env("VGS_SANDBOX_BASE_URL")
  ]
)
```